# Flutter: Error (while using open_file package) - MissingPluginException

Tags: flutter, dart, file, flutter-dependencies

I'm encountering an issue while trying to use the "open_file" package in my Flutter app. When I attempt to open a file, I receive the following error:

`MissingPluginException (No implementation found for method open_file on channel open_file)`

Here are the details of the issue:

**Code:**

```
openFile({required String fileName}) async {
  final File file = await getinvoice(fileName);
  String path = file.path;
  print("opening file:$path, file exists: ${file.existsSync()}");
  OpenFile.open(path);
}
```

**Debug Console:**

```
 opening file:/data/user/0/com.example.wm_invoice/app_flutter/1699176856097.pdf, file exists: true
E/flutter (12369): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method open_file on channel open_file)
E/flutter (12369): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:308:7)
E/flutter (12369): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12369): #1      OpenFile.open (package:open_file/src/platform/open_file.dart:57:21)
E/flutter (12369): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12369):
```

**Description:**
I've been trying to use the "open_file" package in my Flutter app to open PDF files. The code to open a file is straightforward, and it appears that the file exists, as indicated by the file.existsSync() check. However, I'm encountering the "MissingPluginException" error, and the file doesn't open.

I've ensured that the "open_file" package is added to my pubspec.yaml and that I've imported it into my Dart file. I'm using the latest version of the package, and my Flutter environment is up to date.

I would appreciate any guidance on resolving this error and successfully using the "open_file" package to open pdf files in my Flutter app.

Please let me know if you need more information or if there are specific details I should provide. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Do `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get`. Then start the app and try again.

Comment: if you are using other than android/ios you might get this error because the packages doesnt support afaik